# Show tooltip on textbox entry

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, tooltip

I have a `textbox` that requires data to be entered in a certain way. I have implemented some cell validating techniques to check the data after it has been entered, but I'd like to provide the user with some information before they enter the data.

To that end, I'd like to add a `tooltip` to the `textbox` that pops up when the user enters the toolbox, then exits when they begin to type.

For example I have the following code:

```
private void YearEdit_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.IsBalloon = true;
        tt.InitialDelay = 0;
        tt.ShowAlways = true;
        tt.SetToolTip(YearEdit, "Enter 4 digit year.");
    }
```

This executes when the user enters the `textbox`, however the `tooltip` only appears when the mouse hovers over the `textbox`. Does anyone have any ideas to work around this? I thought that perhaps `tt.ShowAlways = true` might work, but obviously not.

Comment: What about putting the code in the `GotFocus` event and then turn it off in the `LostFocus` event

Comment: The polite way to do this is to set the CueText of the control, which renders as a sort of Watermark when the control is empty. This is visually appealing and non-obtrusive.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Hook into the textbox.enter event and use the following code:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TB = (TextBox)sender;
        int VisibleTime = 1000;  //in milliseconds

        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.Show("Test ToolTip", TB, 0, 0, VisibleTime);
    }
```

Play with X/Y values to move it where you want. Visible time is how long until it disappears.

Comment: That's perfect. The location is in reference to the textbox TB, so it should be set to (0,0) to start with.

Comment: Right you are, I initally had it set to the parent window and added the X/Y locations to move it back. Code will be revised.

Answer (score 3):

Tooltips only appear when the mouse is still by design.

You could try setting the [`InitialDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.initialdelay.aspx) to 0:

```
tt.InitialDelay = 0;
```

But this would still require the mouse to be stationary for an instant.

However there are other approaches. A common way of showing what input is required is to use a watermark (faded text) in the textbox that displays the formatting required until the user starts typing.

If you really want a tooltip then you could either add an information icon (usually an "i") which will show the tooltip when it's hovered over, or implement your own.

It might also work if you break the date into parts (separate day, month, year). This will allow you more control over what the user can enter - the month can become a drop down/combo box so it's always the correct format.

Answer (score 3):

you can show a tooltip also like this:

```
ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
t.Show("Hello World", textBox1, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (based on an answer above)
Add event handlers for all controls that you want to have a ToolTip for. Point all the event handlers to the same method. Then construct you handling method like this

```
private void procToolTips(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
   Control o = (Control)sender;
   if ( o.Name == "label1") {
     tt.Show("Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame", o, 1000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `if ( o.Name == label1.Name)` instead of  `if ( o.Name == "label1")`, for if you rename label1, this line will be modified too.

More : `if(o.equals(label1))`...

Comment: This is more of a comment to the answer above, I appreciate you don't have the reputation to make comments but it doesn't make sense as an answer is isolation (especially as the order that answers appear can change), you're best taking text from the answer that user2283985 has given though and changing it to include what you have written above (which is certainly valid).