# c# label shows hover text but textbox doesnt

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, hover, label

If I fill a label text to overflowing it appears that I get a 'tooltip' for free that gives the full text on the label.
It doesn't appear you can select the whole text so I used a disabled textbox - but that has no tooltip on hover functionality. Is that becuase its disabled or just that it doesn't provide that functionality?

Simon

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695357/c-sharp-show-tooltip-on-textbox-entry

Comment: `so I used a disabled textbox`...for what?  How does the textbox relate to the label?  You replaced the label with it?  You duplicated the text in it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable your `TextBox` (of course we have some solution to show a tooltip on a `disabled control` but it still needs more code). Just let it enable as normal, to prevent your `TextBox` from getting focused, try this code:

```
public class NativeTextBox : NativeWindow
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x204) return;//WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201 , WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204                                          
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
//in your form constructor
textBox1.TabStop = false;//This makes your textbox not be focused by KeyBoard.
new NativeTextBox().AssignHandle(textBox1.Handle);
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.SetToolTip(textBox1, "Why can't it work?");
//If you don't want the Text cursor, add this to show the normal standard arrow cursor
textBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it looks like the tooltip still doesn't show even if the textbox is enabled. Turns out it was enabled but had ReadOnly set - anyway I cannot find a combination that gives the tooltip. Probably just a feature of Labels then.

Comment: @user1606413 I don't know how you set tooltip for your `TextBox`, but my code works, see the last two lines in my updated answer.