# How to show tooltil beside a textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a TextBox with ToolTip.

I need to show the ToolTip beside my textBox but how?

```
if (this.txtBoxName.Text == "")

{
    ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
    tip.IsBalloon = false;
    tip.ToolTipTitle = "";
    tip.InitialDelay = 0;
    tip.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    this.txtBoxName.Focus();
    Point point = new Point(750, 560);
    tip.Show("Please Enter UserName", this.txtBoxName);
}
```

Comment: see: [Show tooltip on textbox entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695357/show-tooltip-on-textbox-entry).

Comment: You have to set your point x,y relative to your textbox.

Comment: please use a placeholder text than tooltip for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (this.txtBoxName.Text == null || this.txtBoxName.Text == "")
{
    ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
    tip.IsBalloon = false;
    tip.ToolTipTitle = "";
    tip.InitialDelay = 0;
    tip.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    this.txtBoxName.Focus();
    Point point = new Point(txtBoxName.Location.X - 50, txtBoxName.Location.Y - 50); // for example 50px change
    tip.Show("Please Enter UserName", this.txtBoxName, point, 2000); // set 2000ms to auto close TooTip
}
```

I used this `Show` function `overLoad`, see more info about it:

**`public void Show(string text, IWin32Window window, Point point, int duration);` :**

> **Summary**:
>   Sets the ToolTip text associated with the specified control, and then >displays
>   the ToolTip for the specified duration at the specified relative position.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **text**: 
>   A System.String containing the new ToolTip text.
>
> **window**: 
>   The System.Windows.Forms.Control to display the ToolTip for.
>
> **point**:
>       A System.Drawing.Point containing the offset, in pixels, relative to the
>   upper-left corner of the associated control window, to display the ToolTip.
>
> **duration**:
>   An System.Int32 containing the duration, in milliseconds, to display the
>           ToolTip.
>
> **Exceptions**:
>
> System.ArgumentNullException:
>   The window parameter is null.
>
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   duration is less than or equal to 0.

Comment: It worked thanks. :))

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a template for the textbox

```
<TextBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" />
            <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding TextBox.Text}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

Comment: That's fine. Thanks